# Telerik MVC Contols fail to raise client events with lastest JQuery (1.7.1)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

Telerik MVC Contols fail to raise client events with lastest JQuery (1.7.1)

I've just updated to JQuery 1.7.1 now all my telerik controls fail.

It's late, can anybody confirm this and that it's not just me doing something stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik support has this, sounds like an update is coming: 
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/jquery-1-7.aspx